# Disabling Guest Checkout on Payments with PayPal for recurring payment

Tags: paypal

We have a form that allows users to setup recurring payments. Recurring payments are done using PayPal accounts. Often times users will checkout as a guest, and will pay for the initial installment and will not register using a PayPal account. The end results of this is that the recurring payments aren't being made, as they have used a credit card for their paymeent, and they don't login and approve their recurring transactions.

Is it possible to disable checkout as a guest for recurring payments on a per checkout basis? We don't want this on an account basis, as there are other scenarios where we do want to allow checkout as guest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a bit confused on this, but will give a nice full answer.

The answer depends on which API or product you are using.

**PayPal Standard**
If you are using a "Subscribe" button, by default, customers cannot checkout using guest checkout. They have to use or create a PayPal account to checkout. If you add-on the product *Enhanced Recurring Payments*, then customers can check out without creating a PayPal account, but the subscription will still work as normal.

There is not a way to disable the guest checkout on a per-transaction basis with Standard for non-recurring payments. It is account based.

**Express Checkout**
If you are using the Express Checkout module, you can disable guest checkout on a per-transaction basis by passing the NVP: SOLUTIONTYPE=MARK. However, for a "Recurring Payment" situation, you would be using a "Billing Agreement" or using the RecurringPayments call, both of which disable Guest Checkout similar to PayPal Standard.

Comment: thanks robert - right now, we have a mix of standard & EC, I'll take a look at both to see which is appropriate. i updated the question to make it a little more clear, but you got the gist of what I was trying to ask.